# batch convert htm files to pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion, batch, html

What applications allow the user to batch convert HTM files into PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaining up `html2ps` (http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) and `ps2pdf`. Both are included in all major Linux distribution and are console utilites that you can use in shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use [HTMLDOC](http://www.htmldoc.org/) for this. (Apart from the commandline, it also has a GUI and the option to have it run as a web service via CGI.) There are Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and Unix versions available. You can build your own executable, because the source is available via GPL.