# Batch producing PDFs from a sequence of URLs/multiple URLs

Tags: pdf, conversion, batch, website

Does anyone know of a way of making PDFs from a sequence of URLS/multiple URLs for webpages?  For example, I want to print individual PDFs from a batch of webpages via their URLs.  Is there an alternative to using html2ps and ps2pdf ([batch convert htm files to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/98500/batch-convert-htm-files-to-pdf))? How can I take a list of URLs and convert them to individual PDF files?

Answer (score 2):

Use [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

It's a webkit based web client that outputs to PDF. Being webkit based, it's somewhat modern (though hasn't been updated in a bit), and has CSS support.

Answer (score 2):

First write all your URL's in a .htm file on your computer.

in Acrobat Pro (v9) :

1. Menu file > Create PDF > From Web Page… => Opens the 'Create PDF' window
2. Enter the URL = http/... or in your case browse to the html file you created
3. Click 'Capture Multiple Levels' > Get only = 2 levels
4. Click 'Settings…" to adjust the page size, margins, etc
5. Click 'Create' and wait while Acrobat constructs the file

Answer (score 2):

Weeny is one option. It's a freeware application available at

https://www.weenysoft.com/free-html-to-pdf-converter.html

I've used this to successfully to convert 3000 URLs to PDF.

Comment: Nicely done, you got how this works :-) You're always welcome to add an answer of your own, no matter how old the question is. Even if there already is an accepted answer and you can add something valuable, feel free. Please remember that SE sites aren't forums, but question/answer sites. I took the liberty of toning down your answer a bit, have a look. It's also a good idea to check the Help section, there's good advice. For example here's [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). I'm sure you'll add to the community down the line :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but there's an API for this as well as a copy/paste online window for URLs to PDF - you can find it at https://pdfmyurl.com/batch-web-to-pdf-api and https://pdfmyurl.com/entire-website-to-pdf-advanced

Disclosure - I work for the company that owns this website

Answer (score 0):

If you want a contiguous PDF as a human user would create it by browsing over a website, check with webshot.website. Their free trial is already sufficient in many cases, and if not it is still cheap to get an advanced one.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about this? And can you provide a reference that this is a reputable service? McAfee doesn’t know whether it is safe.

Comment: I repeat: I did not intent to push their site. Just that I found it nice and I did not find others. Please let me know of some if somebody should see such.